# Is it necessary to replace lead gas pipes?

Tags: pipe, gas, lead

I have some lead piping in the cellar where the gas comes into the house. Does this comply to current Gas Safe regulations??

Edit: England

Comment: Which country/state/city?

Comment: @ChrisF i'm from England

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect you actually have two questions:

1) Does it meet current code, and

2) Do I have to do something about it.

My understanding is that in most places you can't do anything new with lead gas pipe, BUT there's no obligation to upgrade old service as long as it's working OK.

My understanding is that most places won't even let you replace lead pipe with more lead pipe - if the pipe goes, you have to replace with something newer. But as long as the pipe is stable, you can leave it there for as long as you like.

Lead gas pipe is somewhat like solid asbestos shingles (which the house I grew up in had as siding) - as long as you don't disturb it, it isn't going to hurt anything, so don't disturb it unless you have to.

Comment: The reason it is treated differently to lead water pipes is that gas pipes should not have water content, so lead will not be dissolved and enter drinking water etc.

Comment: @RoryAlsop - isn't lead pipe also a lot less stable mechanically? Lead is softer than a lot of other metals, and I'd expect that it would be a lot easier to accidentally damage than say iron pipe. I had actually thought that would be a bigger concern than the fact that it happens to be made of lead.

Comment: No - actually they are pretty good in buildings, as they are soft enough that as walls or areas shift, the pipes flex. It isn't that easy to accidentally damage them.

Comment: The softness of lead is helpful, as minor settling will simply deform the pipe.